# Inner @gen.coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

I want to run asynchronous method, which run other asynchronous methods, which run other asynchronous methods by using  @tornado.gen.coroutine decorator. 
Something like that:

```
@gen.coroutine
def download1():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    res = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
    do_something_with_response1(res)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

@gen.coroutine
def download2():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    res = yield http_client.fetch("http://example2.com")
    do_something_with_response2(res)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

@gen.coroutine
def big_download():
    res1 = yield download1()
    res2 = yield download2()
    res = do_something_with_responses(res1, res2)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        res = yield big_download()
        self.write(res)
```

Can I do this? How?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Try running it. Do you have a question?

Comment: Your code is ok. Additionally `big_download` can start both downloads  `res1, res2 = yield [download1(), download2()]`